# jQuery client side filter system

Tags: jquery, filter

For some reason the last item with data ID 'property-company', will not display when all of its values are checked i.e. Email, Branding and Property. I noticed that when the values placed inside the data-category tag are in the same order as the checkbox values it works, but the values will be added dynamically so the order can't be controlled.

Here is the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/amesy/kwqpf5fv/1/

Here is the jQuery...

```
$(function() {

var $checkboxes = $("input[id^='type-']");
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').attr('checked', false);

$checkboxes.change(function() {
    console.log($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length);
    if( $('input[type=checkbox]:checked'
         ).length>0)
{
    var selector1 = '';
    var selector2 = '';
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() { // checked 
        selector1 += $(this).attr('rel') + ' ';
        selector2 = $(this).attr('rel') + ' ' + selector2;
        // builds a selector like '.A, .B, .C, ' 
    });
    selector1= selector1.substring(0, selector1.length - 2); // remove trailing ', '
    selector2= selector2.substring(0, selector2.length - 2); // remove trailing ', '
    $('[data-category]').hide() // hide all rows
     .filter(function() {
         if ($(this).data('category').indexOf(selector1) != -1 ||     $(this).data('category').indexOf(selector2) != -1) { return true; } else { return false; }; 
    }).show(); // reduce set to matched and show

}else

{
 $('[data-category]').show()    
}
});

});
```

here is the html...

```
<div class="tags">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="type-Website" rel="Website">Website</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="type-Email" rel="Email">Email</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="type-Branding" rel="Branding">Branding</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="type-Automotive" rel="Automotive">Automotive</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="type-Property" rel="Property">Property</label>
    </div>

<div class="portfolio-item" data-id="one-page-website" data-category="Automotive Email Website" style="display: block;">

            <h1 class="entry-title">One Page Website</h1>

        </div>

<div class="portfolio-item" data-id="some-logo" data-category="Branding Property" style="display: block;">

            <h1 class="entry-title">some Logo</h1>

        </div>

<div class="portfolio-item" data-id="some-email-campaign" data-category="Automotive Email" style="display: block;">

            <h1 class="entry-title">Some Email Campaign</h1>

        </div>

<div class="portfolio-item" data-id="some-brand" data-category="Automotive Branding Email" style="display: block;">

            <h1 class="entry-title">some brand</h1>

        </div>

<div class="portfolio-item" data-id="property-company" data-category="Branding Email Property" style="display: block;">

            <h1 class="entry-title">Stationery</h1>

        </div>
```

Comment: because for 3 checkboxes you get 6 combinations, for 4 checkboxes 24 combinations (etc..). Why not use classes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two selectors with opposite sequence of categories.

That will only work for two selected categories where the combinations are only 2.

For 3 selected categories you get 6 combinations, for 4 selected you get 24 combinations etc..

You need to either split the categories to an array and check if each element matches all of the selected categories (*checking one at a time*) or use classes which allows for native selectors.

Here is a solution using classes (*you need to move the categories to the classes attribute*)
(*I also changed the `rel` attribute on the checkboxes to the `value` attribute as it is easier and more meaningful*)

```
$(function () {

    var $checkboxes = $("input[id^='type-']");
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').attr('checked', false);

    $checkboxes.change(function () {
        var selector = '',
            count = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            selector += '.' + this.value; // create `.a.b.c` selector
        }).length,
            items = $('.portfolio-item');

        if (count>0) {
            items.hide().filter(selector).show();
        } else {
            items.show();
        }
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwqpf5fv/4/

Answer (score 0):

i changed the order of the data-category and it worked.

```
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-id="property-company" data-category="Property Branding Email" style="display: block;">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Stationery</h1>
    </div>
```

i would suggest using classes for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your full code. The javascript is updated:

```
function StringContainsAllItems(stringVal, items){
   if(items.length == 0 || items.length == null){
    return false;   
}

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    console.log("Item: " + items[i]);
    if(stringVal.indexOf(items[i]) == -1)
    {
         return false;   
    }
}

return true;
}


$(function() { 
    var $checkboxes = $("input[id^='type-']");
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').attr('checked', false);

    $checkboxes.change(function() {
        if( $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0){

        var selectorArray = [];

        $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
            selectorArray.push($(this).attr('rel'));
            console.log($(this).attr('rel'));             
        });

        $('[data-category]').hide() // hide all rows
         .filter(function() {
             return StringContainsAllItems($(this).data('category'), selectorArray);             
        }).show(); // reduce set to matched and show

    }else
        {
         $('[data-category]').show();   
        }
   });    
});
```

here it is in a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kwqpf5fv/5/

Enjoy.

Comment: The posted code is not the code in the jsfiddle (*and the code in the fiddle will match substrings*).